# What song is playing in DBS Episode 130 at around 9:40?

Tags: music, dragon-ball-super

So I've heard this song with the previous fight of Goku with Kefla and Jiren.
It also is featured in Episode 130 and begins at around 9:40. And for the record, I've tried Shazam and other similar services.

If possible, plz link the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the song, from the original soundtrack vol. 2. "The Power to Resist"

Answer (score 0):

"The Power to Resist" is correct. I've got the song synced to the fight from the original episode.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HHBi-5Pgln0

Comment: Maybe this would be better as a comment to the accepted answer?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you @JonLin